# Do not include fixed value in JSON SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2017

I have to make JSON from the table.
Problem is, that I have to show NULL values, but hide all fixed constant values.

For example, I have dataset `#table`. In the JSON output I want to show all values, where `Value != 0`. 
Deleting row `(select Value from #table where cn = 'c') as 'c'` isn't an option.
How can I do that?

```
create table #table (
   Value int,
   cn nvarchar(1)
)

insert into #table
values
(null, 'a'),
(null, 'b'),
(0, 'c'),
(3, 'd'),
(3, 'f')

select
    (select Value from #table where cn = 'a')  as 'a',
    (select Value from #table where cn = 'b') as 'b', 
    (select Value from #table where cn = 'c') as 'c', 
    (select Value from #table where cn = 'd') as 'd', 
    (select Value from #table where cn = 'f') as 'f'
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Expected output would be:

```
[{"a":null,"b":null,"d":3,"f":3}]
```

Comment: you want to hide null values?

Comment: No, I want to show null values, but hide all values, which contains `0` (as in example) or another fixed (not null) value.

Comment: Ok, I got your point :)

Comment: can we set if values has `0` then we set `null` or you won't hide those columns in JSON response

Comment: O want to hide/delete all fields in json response, which contains `0` values. All other values, which are `null` has to be shown in json response.

Comment: Is dynamic sql an option?

Comment: @Serg, yes, it is an option

Comment: See the answer with dynamic sql .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a dynamic sql. I use conditional aggregation to pivot the table.

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + stuff(
    (select  ', max(case cn when ''' + cn + ''' then value end) as ''' + cn +''''
     from #table
     where value <> 0 or value is null
     for xml path(''))
    , 1, 1, '') + ' from #table FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES';

 --select @cmd;

 exec (@cmd);
```

Another option builds on the type of the `value` column (`int`), so `0.5` is impossible as a column value. Cast the original values to decimal, then replace impossible values with `null` and remove decimal point and `0` after it.

```
select replace(replace(
  (select
    max(case cn when 'a' then value end) 'a',
    max(case cn when 'b' then value end) 'b',
    max(case cn when 'c' then value end) 'c',
    max(case cn when 'd' then value end) 'd',
    max(case cn when 'f' then value end) 'f'
  from( 
   select coalesce(cast(value as decimal), 0.5) value, cn 
   from #table
   where value <> 0 or value is null) t
   FOR JSON PATH)
,'0.5', 'null'), '.0', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can vary the number of selected column in a SQL statement, but you can do this:

```
declare @statement varchar(max) ='
select
    (select Value from #table where cn = ''a'')  as ''a'',
    (select Value from #table where cn = ''b'') as ''b'', 
    --(select Value from #table where cn = ''c'') as ''c'', 
    (select Value from #table where cn = ''d'') as ''d'', 
    (select Value from #table where cn = ''f'') as ''f''
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES'


exec sp_sqlexec @statement
```

Effectively build you SQL statement, to only select those values which are not equal to the value you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

It is not elegant, but one possibility is manually building the string:

```
select concat('[{',
              string_agg(concat('"', cn, '":', coalesce(convert(varchar(255), value), 'null')
                               ), ','
                        ), '}]'
             )
from t
where value <> 0 or value is null
```